# Complex Modulus Is Less Than One

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $|\frac{-a}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}|<1$ where $a>|b|>0$

This is just a minor part of a more full complex trigonometric integral proof that I'm working on. I'm pretty much set once I can show this inequality is true. Please Help!

What I was thinking was:
$|\frac{-a}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}|=|\frac{-a}{b}+\frac{a}{b}\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}|$

Then $\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}<1$, Which implies $\frac{a}{b}\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}<\frac{a}{b}$

The problem is, this doesn't guarantee that first inequality is true, in less I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\sqrt{a^2-b^2}-a = \frac{a^2-b^2-a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}+a}$$

details:
$$
0\le a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}
 = \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}+a}\le |b| \frac {|b|}a\le |b|$$

Comment: could the downvoter elaborate?

Comment: Awesome, this worked out perfectly, I saw where you were going before your edit and I'm frustrated I didn't think of it! Thank you so much!